# Search for solve a error 255 in SOLR Nutch

Tags: solr, nutch

I have allready tested SOLR with Nutch on local machine and it runs without Errors. Now I have deploy it to live server and got this error 255

```
enter code here


  Indexing 139/139 documents
Deleting 0 documents
Indexing job did not succeed, job status:FAILED, reason: NA
Indexer: java.lang.RuntimeException: Indexing job did not succeed, job status:FAILED, reason: NA
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:150)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:291)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:300)

Error running:
  /home/apache-nutch-1.18/runtime/local/bin/nutch index -Dsolr.server.url=http://localhost:8984/solr/nutch -Dmapreduce.job.reduces=2 -Dmapreduce.reduce.speculative=false -Dmapreduce.map.speculative=false -Dmapreduce.map.output.compress=true crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/20220728170007 -deleteGone
```

enter code here

Failed with exit value 255.
Anyone an idea what this can be?

Answer (score 0):

Show if the core exists in SOLR
install ant if not present
go to $NUTCH_HOME and run > apt runtime
Thats all folks and will now run and write